# Problem with Headless when running selenium test using java

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, automated-tests, headless

I have a problem with running a test in headless mode. I wrote my test cases in two different (web shop and portal). Likewise, I am using Headless, my test works when headless is true in web-shop, but they don't work when headless is true in portal test cases.

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click
> intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (480, 483). Other element
> would receive the click: ...   (Session info:
> headless chrome=91.0.4472.114) Build info: version: '4.0.0-beta-3',
> revision: '5d108f9a67' System info: host: 'moin-mkt-007.local', ip:
> 'fe80:0:0:0:1412:539b:3727:1402%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:
> 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '14.0.2' Driver info:
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Command:
> [d05ff1a9794fef32216ef34021b22337, clickElement
> {id=de6be461-9b49-4e10-8d99-c008af09b8ae}] Capabilities
> {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion:
> 91.0.4472.114, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 91.0.4472.101 (af52a90bf870..., userDataDir: /var/folders/p9/0lhk_6lj7x7...},
> goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:9222},
> javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false,
> pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy:
> Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:9222/devtool..., se:cdpVersion:
> 91.0.4472.114, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000},
> unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify,
> webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators:
> true} Element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC
> (d05ff1a9794fef32216ef34021b22337)] -> id: username] Session ID:
> d05ff1a9794fef32216ef34021b22337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not present your code here, but I guess you are missing maximizing screen in headless mode.
So I think something like this should solve your problem:

```
opts.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors");
```

Comment: Sorry i cant share codes here because there are differents classes, but i tried all these ways and it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of few things :

1. Set the browser resolution to maximum :

   ```
   driver.maximize_window()
   ```

or if using chrome options :

```
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
```

2. Make use of **ActionChains** :

   ```
   ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(your web element here).click.perform()
   ```

This will be the **imports** :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

In place of `your web element here` you would need to pass `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "some xpath")`

Comment: i did all but unfortunatlly it doesnt work,can we have a call with teams together ?

Comment: before that can you share URL ? if it's public

Comment: i do my tests in this two sites

Comment: neither of them loaded in my local

Answer (score 0):

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException
It display this exception when other element obscures the desired element

try to click on the element with the WebDriverWait locator stretegy

new WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(10))
    .ignoring(ElementClickInterceptedException.class)
    .until(ExpectedConditions
    .elementToBeClickable(By.id("web_element")))
    .click();

As you are executing the script in the headless mode, so
options.addArguments("--headless","--disable-notifications","--window-size=1920,1080")

* this is mentioned in the other answers as well
```